# DIRECTQUERY Grab value from another row to current row value

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to grab value from END_TIME and put it in same row as START_TIME when it's same ID. First example shows how my table is built. Second how I want it. I'm running this in DirectQuery mode. How would you solve this?

| ID | START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:31 |  |
| 1 |  | 16:54 |
| 2 | 00:05 |  |
| 2 |  | 03:21 |
| 3 | 19:03 |  |
| 3 |  | 20:01 |

| ID | START_TIME | END:TIME | END_TIME_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:31 |  | 16:54 |
| 1 |  | 16:54 |  |
| 2 | 00:05 |  | 03:21 |
| 2 |  | 03:21 |  |
| 3 | 19:03 |  | 20:01 |
| 3 |  | 20:01 |  |